# Twenty nine-letter words

Tags: word, english

I took twenty 9-letter everyday English words from the Merriam-Webster dictionary, broke them into sixty 3-letter pieces and ordered the sixty pieces alphabetically:

```
    acc all ant but day dif eap eid ent ent ent eph equ erd erf ess eth far fer fly  
    gar hol imp ine ing ion ipm lio lpo mar mho myt nes new nut ogy one ort ory own  
    pin ple por rec rel rit row sag sca sco som tel ter tfo und use wat wed wer wil
```

What are the twenty 9-letter words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These should be all twenty:

> different mythology telephone equipment portfolio 
>  pineapple willpower margarine wednesday important 
>  waterfall butterfly scarecrow accessory nutrition 
>  scoundrel eiderdown farmhouse something newsagent

I found about half of them myself, so credit to the other answers as well. I think they only missed one between them (last one in my list).

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find 18 so far:

> willpower 
>  margarine 
>  portfolio 
>  wednesday 
>  mythology 
>  farmhouse 
>  telephone 
>  eiderdown 
>  pineapple 
>  waterfall 
>  scoundrel 
>  equipment 
>  important 
>  scarecrow 
>  differing 
>  accessory 
>  butterfly 
>  nutrition

Comment: the one you have ending in "ing" should be "ent", this would allow you to round out the last two with "something" and "newsagent" - very, very close!

Answer (score 3):

This is not the full answer, but more is not possible with my dictionary

> different, butterfly, equipment, important, mythology, pineapple, something, portfolio, telephone, wednesday, willpower, recession, margarine, farmhouse and maybe eiderdown

One of the problems is "ter". There is

> territory, scatering, waterfall

and this results in multiple answers. If nobody will find the rest I extend my lines with some bruteforcing logic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "scatering" is a typo in your dictionary and not an actual word.

Comment: "Waterfall" is wat + erf + all, so it doesn't actually use the ter piece.

Comment: thank you.. scatering is in real scattering ... I should use another dict.

Comment: ter is in butterfly